# How to remove javascript code from wordpress rest api

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

When I call wordpress api every call return with this javascript code which is unnecessary for me. I'm new to wordpress so I don't know how to remove this code for api call. and why this is happen in api call

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"><script>
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $("#woocommerce_alfalahbankaccount_merchantID").prop("required", true);
                    $("#woocommerce_alfalahbankaccount_password").prop("required", true);
                    $("#woocommerce_alfalahbankaccount_returnURL").prop("required", true);
                    $("#woocommerce_alfalahbankaccount_expiryHours").prop("required", true);
                    $("#woocommerce_alfalahbankaccount_integritySalt").prop("required", true);
                    $("#woocommerce_alfalahbankaccount_actionURL").prop("required", true);
    });</script>
```

below responce is ok

```
{
 "id": 2008,
 "date": "2021-08-31T12:31:41",
"date_gmt": "2021-08-31T07:31:4
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).